# How to find the number of spheroids bound by two parallel planes or cuboid, and plot these?

Tags: r, plot, 3d, geometry, rgl

I am looking for a library or other source code that will help me display non-intersecting spheres or spheroids, not necessarily a bin packing issue, but it could be. Each of these spheres can also contain a further set of much smaller spheres within. I would then like to take a slice, i.e. two parallel planes a distance apart or a cuboid, through this "world", and calculate how many larger as well as smaller spheres are "captured" by the given slice, and to generate a 3D graphic.

Although I have plenty of experience in programming, etc. 3D spaces are new to me, and my geometry a bit rusty. I've looked into the rgl package for R+ as well as D3.js, but don't see an obvious solution. I've searched through StackOverflow and there is the "Cube sphere intersection test?" post, but it doesn't quite get me what I'm looking for. Not sure if this falls under a "collision" problem or more of a stereology problem perhaps, but the CRAN package StereoMorph also didn't yield any answers.

Any suggestions as to where I should look are welcome. I'm also not wed to any particular computer language.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A sphere is defined as:

```
[centerX,centerY,centerZ,radius]
```

and a plane is defined as

```
[normalVectorX,normalVectorY,normalVectorZ,distance]
```

Distance is the distance from the origin to the plane if you were to travel along the direction of the normal vector. In other words, if you multiply each component of the normal vector by distance you will have a point somewhere on the plane.

To test if a sphere is on one side of the plane or the other:

Project the sphere center onto the plane normal, add the radius of the sphere, and if that sum is less than the plane distance, then it has not intersected.

```
CENTER = [centerX,centerY,centerZ]
NORMAL = [normalVectorX,normalVectorY,normalVectorZ]
isBelowHighPlane = dotProduct(CENTER,NORMAL)+radius < distance
```

For the other plane, lets say the "lower" plane, subtract the radius and test if the sum is greater:

```
isAboveLowPlane = dotProduct(CENTER,NORMAL)-radius > distance
```

Therefore, if both the above tests are true the sphere is contained.

NOTE: If your plane is defined some other way, for example by three points in space A,B,C, you can find the normal by taking the cross product of any two sides:

```
normalVector = normalize(crossProduct((B-A),(B-C)))
```

And once you have that normal vector, you can find the distance by projecting the vector from the origin to any of those points onto the normal:

```
distance = dotProduct(B,normalVector)
```

Note, distance may be negative.

So the 3d functions you need in whatever language you choose are:

`dotProduct()`, `crossProduct()`, and `normalize()`

If you have some connection from small spheres to their containing big sphere, and that big sphere is either completely in or completely out, then you can instantly know the state of all the small spheres. However, to test if a big sphere is completely out, you'll need extra variations on the test:

```
isAboveHighPlane = dotProduct(CENTER,NORMAL)-radius > distance
isBelowLowPlane = dotProduct(CENTER,NORMAL)+radius < distance
```